# Azure bot composer CICD using github actions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bots, github-actions, botframework

I want to know if there is any way of deploying bot code made in Azure bot composer locally and code pushed to GitHub and further using GitHub actions that code needs to be deployed to Azure web app.

I have gone through Microsoft's official documentation regarding bot composer CI/CD but that includes code in .net and using only Azure DevOps. I could not find any way to deploy a node js-based bot made  using bot composer and deployed using GitHub actions

I know about workflow and GitHub action but do not know about bot templates and steps of the workflow to deploy it

Comment: Please share your GitHub repository link.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below steps to deploy NodeJS Bot Application which was generated via Bot composer to Azure.**

- I have created a ***NodeJs Bot Application via Bot Composer*** and running as expected locally.

[image]

After creating the project, navigate to Scripts folder of your project in Terminal and run the below commands:

- **This is to provision new Azure resources.**

```
npm install
node provisionComposer.js --subscriptionId=<YOUR AZURE SUBSCRIPTION ID> --name=<NAME OF YOUR RESOURCE GROUP> --appPassword=<APP PASSWORD> --environment=<NAME FOR ENVIRONMENT DEFAULT to dev>
```

(or)

You can also provision the Azure resources in Bot composer.

- Click on **Publish** icon in Bot Composer=>Select your project=>Manage profiles
  [image: Se]
- **It'll redirect to publishing profile=>*Add New*=>Select *Publish bot to Azure* and Submit.**

[image]

[image]

- **Configure resources as shown below:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

- **Pushed the whole project code to GitHub:**

[image]

- Go to your newly created `web app=>Deployment Center=>Select source as GitHub and select GitHub repository of your Bot Project`. This will initiate and deploy the project to App Service:

[image]

You can check the Publish Configuration in `Project=>Settings=>appsettings.json`,

```json
"publishTargets": [
    {
      "configuration": "{\n  \"name\": \"kpnodewebapp\",\n  \"environment\": \"composer\",\n  \"tenantId\": \"72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47\",\n  \"subscriptionId\": \"b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f\",\n  \"resourceGroup\": \"resourcegroupname\",\n  \"botName\": \"<azurebotname>\",\n  \"hostname\": \"webappname\",\n  \"runtimeIdentifier\": \"win-x64\",\n  \"region\": \"westus\",\n  \"appServiceOperatingSystem\": \"linux\",\n  \"settings\": {\n    \"applicationInsights\": {},\n    \"luis\": {},\n    \"qna\": {},\n    \"MicrosoftAppId\": \"2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7447\",\n    \"MicrosoftAppPassword\": \"QYS8Q~1UXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXW-SYRcHjbiP\"\n  }\n}",
      "name": "webappname",
      "type": "azurePublish"
    }
  ],
```

**Portal:**

- I could deploy and test the bot as shown below:

[image]